# ES6 string to ReadableStream

Tags: javascript, stream

If I have a function which accepts a `ReadableStream<string>`, but I want to call it with a `string` argument, is the following the easiest/best way to handle it?

```js
const stringToStream = str => new ReadableStream({
    start(controller){
        controller.enqueue(str);
        controller.close();
    }
});

readableStreamFunc(stringToStream("foo"))
```

Answer (score -1):

ReadableStream.from(...) is in the works

https://github.com/whatwg/streams/issues/1018